# Expression for some special SQL queries

Tags: phrase-requests, programming, technical, terminology

While I'm not native English speaker, I often need to express myself in English.

For a week, I have been searching for a term which represents a kind of SQL query:

```
SELECT something FROM somewhere WHERE somethingElse IN (SELECT foo FROM bar)
```

It's a query within another (those in brackets). What term should I use to describe it?

- A nested query
- An embedded query
- An included query
- A sub-query
- Another term?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This form is called a [subselect](http://www.fluffycat.com/SQL/Subselect/) by [IBM](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iadthelp/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.etools.iseries.langref2.doc/rbafzmst292.htm). However, a more popular synonym is a [subquery](http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql-subquery.htm), which is used by [Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.0-en/subqueries.html). One page says

> Subquery or Inner query or Nested query is a query in a query.

Usage on Stackoverflow:

- Subquery, 27,768 posts, 2,552 tags
- Subselect, 3,596 posts, 218 tags
- Inner query, 1,439 posts, 19 tags
- Nested query, 835 posts, 106 tags

I suggest you use either of the two most popular terms.

Comment: I suspect the reason ‘subquery’ is by far the most common term is that perhaps the two biggest players in the SQL field use it: Oracle (as you mention) and [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/subqueries.html).

Comment: If you search for "subselect mysql" the top hit is the subquery page that you cited. (By the way, it's not surprising that Oracle and MySQL use the same terminology. See http://www.oracle.com/us/products/mysql/mysqlenterprise/overview/index.html.)

Answer (score 2):

Not really sure this is about the English language as such (it might be better on Stack Overflow), but that's a [subquery, also known as an inner or nested query](http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql-subquery.htm).

Comment: +1. I'd add that *subquery* is jargon, as such the best place to look for these sorts of problems is English-language technical writing on SQL (or for whatever field the jargon is used in) rather than general resources about the English language.

Answer (score 1):

"Nested query" is the term I'd use ([example on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12467354/nesting-queries-in-sql)), but I've also seen them called [subqueries or inner queries](http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql-subquery.htm).